# Passing props from child function to parent function with React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Within Session() I want to access stateABC, which is in Item5().

The setup of my code looks like this:

Session.js:

```
function Session() {
//get handleRender(item).props.stateABC here
    return (
        <View>
            {handleRender(item)}
        </View>
    );
}
```

handleRender.js:

```
export function handleRender(item) {

    if(item == "Item5"){
        return (
                {Item5()}
            );
    }
}
```

Item5.js:

```
 export function Item5() {
    
        const [stateABC, setStateABC] = useState("123"); 
    
        return (
                    ....
                );
    }
```

I tried to get the value in Session() by using handleRender(item).props.stateABC, but all I get is an empty value.

Is it possible to receive properties from a function like that or are props only accessible in class components?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you need to access to `stateABC` value from `Session` component you have to pass a callback prop down from `Session` to `Item5` and call it every time you update `stateABC` with `setStateABC`, passing the new value to the callback.

This is the simplest approach, you could also use `React Context API` or even something like `Redux` if you think that your app will grow in complexity.

Also, the approach that you tried to use is a bad idea. It works only in class component but in any case you should not use it, it's a bad thing to access props directly.

Comment: thanks for your response. 
lets assume Item05 is a counter with the following line of code on button click:
setCounterState(counterState => { return { "count": counterState.count + 1 } });
=> from my understanding, this is a callback function. Am I wrong?

Comment: and which approach would you suggest, if mine is a bad one?

Comment: Yes that is a callback function, but you need to manage the "link" between the states of your `Session` and `Item5` components. So you need to manage the local state of `Item5` and, every time it changes, you have to execute a callback function passed from your `Session` that will update `Session`s state. The code that do this depends on your project, so I can't be more detailed. Please take a look on this in order to understand better: https://medium.com/@jasminegump/passing-data-between-a-parent-and-child-in-react-deea2ec8e654